# Resuming Session on an already deployed contract on remmix

Tags: solidity, remix

I deployed a solidity contract on remix, I closed my remix tab and resumed it when i wanted to, I imported the code from my file manager and compiled it but getting null from all my functions.

How can i resume back to the session?

Comment: Where did you deploy the contract? The default option is to "Javascript VM", a transient VM that only exist in the browser while the tab is open. If you close the tab you have to deploy again.

Comment: I used injected web3

Comment: What's network? What's the contract address?

Comment: I haven't used that network. The contract seem to be there. Did you try using the "At Address" box to get the contract?

Comment: Yes, it worked when i used the at address box, but the functions are returning null.

Comment: Did you configure the enviroment with injected web? and swith to the correct network in Metamask (or the wallet you were using)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134288/discussion-between-ismael-and-perfdev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the contract address, put it in the At Address box and make sure you are on the same workspace and on the same file which you had deployed to the blockchain. Then click the At Address button and everything should work fine.